# SendEmail pipeline showing "Could not resolve type name error" while adding pipeline- sitecore emailcampaign

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I have created a class

```c#
public class ECMSendMessageProcessor
{
    public void Process(SendMessageArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

And added a pipeline on "SendEmail"

```xml
<SendEmail>
  <processor type="Namespace.ClassName.Method,Assembly" />
```

While i send email am facing
Could not resolve type name "Namespace.ClassName.Method,Assembly"

Reference link http://www.craigtaylor.us/2014/10/injecting-tracking-pixel-into-sitecore-ecm.html
I tried changing the pipeline, class etc. But always showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying your custom processor, don't include the method name. Change your example to this:

```xml
<SendEmail>
  <processor type="Namespace.ClassName,Assembly" />
```

Comment: I tried this without adding method name. But I am facing the same error

Comment: You most likely have a typo in your declaration

Answer (score 1):

You should just use just the ClassName in your declaration rather than adding the method on the end e.g

```xml
 <SendEmail>
      <processor type="Namespace.ClassName, Assembly" />
```

The process() method is the default method for a pipeline processor. If you wanted to use another method other than process you can add Method="yourmethod" to the declaration.

Comment: Are you sure your assembly has been deployed to the webroot and the class and assembly names are correct?

Comment: Yes. I did solution build and published and also assembly names are correct